# Debian machine makes repeated requests to DNS for <gateway_ip>.in-addr.arpa

Tags: debian, logs, dns, router

I recently forwarded all my router logs to my Debian machine.
I noticed a repeated entry in the router logs. The entry is:

> Sep 14 17:07:29 192.168.0.1 [Host 192.168.0.1] UDP 192.168.0.2,38048 --> {ip_of_my_isp_dns_server},53 ALLOW: Outbound access request [DNS query for 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.]

I have the following questions:

1. Is that normal? Why is the Debian machine trying to resolve its own ip in dns?
2. How can I figure out what application on my Debian machine sends these DNS requests?

Comment: That log entry says that .2 is trying to reverse resolve .1, not itself.  Just `ping`'ing the router would be enough to generate such requests.  `netstat -r` or `traceroute` would do the same.

Comment: thanks. my mistake. Anyway 192.168.0.1 is a gateway ip address. Why does Debian need to resolve it?

Comment: I think I found the answer. It is [here](http://lists.adiscon.net/pipermail/rsyslog/2012-February/029512.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [link](http://lists.adiscon.net/pipermail/rsyslog/2012-February/029512.html) is related. One of the solutions is to run rsyslogd daemon with -x parameter. rsyslog will stop doing dns lookups. But I suppose it is not suitable for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that normal? Why is the Debian machine trying to resolve its own ip in dns?

Yes, those are [reverse DNS lookups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). Something on your machine is trying to resolve IPs to their respective hostnames. That is absolutely normal; almost all programs that display IPs do this (for example ping, route, netstat).

> How can I figure out what application on my Debian machine sends these DNS requests?

I'm not really sure how one could do that. I wouldn't bother, because as I said, this is absolutely normal. Try the following commands to see the difference between resolving IPs and not resolving IPs; you will notice that the latter is much faster:

```
ping google.com
ping -n google.com
route
route -n
netstat
netstat -n
```

Comment: You are right. I just read netstat help more carefully and I found who did that. I ran **netstat -u -a -n -W -c -p | grep 89.101.160.5** and I found that rsyslog was doing that. But I still do not understand why Debian is trying to make a dns request instead of saying to a requested application that it requests a host ip

Comment: I made a mistake. Actually it tries to resolve not itself ip but gateway ip. But anyway it looks strange for me that Debian is trying to resolve gateway ip address in DNS.

Comment: As I said - many utilities try to resolve IPs to hostnames by default, just for convenience reasons. These utilities usually have a -n parameter that prevents this, which is useful when the DNS requests are causing the utility to slow down too much. If you are sure that it's caused by rsyslog - are you using network logging in some way?

Comment: Yes. I found a solution. I put a link in a comment to my post. As you said rsyslog should be executed with -x option.